# Proxy Config error while installing angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-routing

I want to install angular cli through node.js command prompt
`>npm install -g @angular/cl`

I also set `npm set config proxy http proxy`

And every time I am getting this error. please find the attached image.[image]

Comment: Does your proxy address start with http://?

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt my proxy is like this : `npm set config proxy 123.121.123:1005`

Comment: have you tried setting it like this: `npm set config proxy http://123.121.123:1005`